# Add stars to p<.05 in correlation matrix in Stata

Tags: stata

I'm hoping to one star to p<.05 and two stars to p<.001 in a correlation matrix in Stata. This is the code that I'm currently using. The code still generates a correlation matrix, but no stars appear in places where they should. Thanks for your help!

```
asdoc corr RELATIONSHIP anxiety BEH_SIM SIM_VALUES sptconf NEG_EFFICACY spteffort SPTEFFORT_OTHER COOP_MOTIV COMP_MOTIV, star(0.5), replace
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to use `pwcorr` rather than `corr` to be able to add stars to your correlation matrix. Second, you should not have the second comma right after the `star` option.

For example, the code below will output a correlation matrix with 1 star if significant at a 10% level, 2 stars if significant at 5% level, and three stars if significant at a 1%
level.

```
asdoc pwcorr var1 var2 var3, star(all) replace
```

I do not believe you can specify star numbers and significant levels the way you would like to using `asdoc`. You can specify custom significance levels by using `star(.05)` rather than `star(all)` as I do above, but this will put one star by every correlation coefficient significant at a 5% level and I do not think you can specify more than 1 level at a time.

The author of `asdoc` is Professor Attaullah Shah. He is very helpful and responsive so you might ask him. If not currently possible, if you ask he may add your suggestion to a future `asdoc` update. Here is a link to his website: https://fintechprofessor.com/2019/06/01/export-correlation-table-to-word-with-stars-and-significance-level-using-asdoc/